# Styling <input type="text"> on mobile Firefox

Tags: firefox, fennec

Having tried applying CSS `border`, `outline` and `appearance` rules to no effect, is there a way to get rid of the default inset shadows and rounded corners of `<input type="text">` in Fennec (mobile Firefox)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: apparently it's just a background image. So `background-image:none;` should do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/6PbFk/
<strike>AFAIK it's not currently possible due to this bug:</strike> 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718847#c10